# No virtual method setOnScrollChangeListener(Landroidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView$OnScrollChangeListener;)V in class NestedScrollView

Tags: android

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setOnScrollChangeListener(Landroidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView$OnScrollChangeListener;)V 
in class Landroidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView; or its super classes 
(declaration of 'androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView' appears in base.apk) at 
... 
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
```

I got this error in pre-launch report at the last line below in many versions including 30.

```
    scrollView = binding.itemDetailScrollView;
    scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(
            (androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener) 
    (view, i, i1, i2, i3) -> showHeaderAtEnd());
```

The fragment/app itself is working fine when installed from appstore testing and it was working fine in the last pre-launch report with this line in place. There are no upgrades to any libraries between these two versions (in fact no change in .gradle except for the version upgrade); This file was also not touched between the releases.

Anyone else getting this eror recently in firebase pre-launch tests?

Comment: I got a similar error. It seems a call to `NestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP)` causes the error. Not found in `androidx.test.tools.crawler` it says?

Comment: Registered an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213617215). Please check if it is related.

Comment: @l33t - yes, it seems to be the same issue, thank you. Please feel free to add it as the answer, if you like. btw, I simply resubmitted the same release with a different version and it passed the second time.

Answer (score 1):

[As @l33t didn't update here, I am posting the discussion in comments as the answer for future reference.]

It was due to Firebase pre-launch testing system acting up and a resubmission and re-run passed again [of course, with no change in code].

Although we need to blame ourselves before faulting OS, compiler or frameworks, this is one instance where the framework was at issue; See the related issue from @l33t - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/213617215

Comment: Did you by any chance use `exclude group` in build.gradle? I'm still suspecting that an exclusion of a library caused this problem for me. (Haven't yet verified this theory as I immediately re-added the library, and since then firebase is happy.)

Comment: No - I didn't touch anything in either build and  the first failed and the second passed.